# wget convert tgz file to HTML

Tags: debian, wget, file-types

I'm trying to download a *.tgz* file under debian so I decided to use `wget` for this. This is my command line :

```
~$ wget http://www.netmet-solutions.org/download/netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz
```

I got the file and I want to *tar* so I do

```
~$ tar -zxvf netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz
```

and it says that

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
```

So I check the file and this appear

```
netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz: HTML document, ISO-8859 text, with very long lines
```

*wget* transformed a *tgz* file in HTML and I don't know why.

Any ideas? Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.netmet-solutions.org/download/netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz has a redirect enforced to http://www.netmet-solutions.org/Telechargement/Telechargement (a standard HTML page). So basically, you are not downloading the .tgz file, but a simple HTML page. The output of wget confirms the redirect:

```
➤ wget http://www.netmet-solutions.org/download/netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz
--2017-04-14 11:14:43--  http://www.netmet-solutions.org/download/netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz
Resolving www.netmet-solutions.org... 193.50.27.134
Connecting to www.netmet-solutions.org|193.50.27.134|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /Telechargement/Telechargement [following]
--2017-04-14 11:14:44--  http://www.netmet-solutions.org/Telechargement/Telechargement
Connecting to www.netmet-solutions.org|193.50.27.134|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz'
```

**EDIT:** Basically, you have to accept the CeCILL license , in order to download the archive (http://www.netmet-solutions.org/Telechargement/Jaccepte). To do this via wget, you will need to pass the expected cookie, in the header:

```
wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: accepted_licence=chocolat" http://www.netmet-solutions.org/download/netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz
```

, where the resulted file will be recognized as gzip compressed data:

```
➤ file netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz
netMETdistrib-4.5_5.8_20160322.tgz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Tue Mar 22 12:39:36 2016, from Unix
```